# Return data from a DevExpress XtraDialog

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

I'm using Visual Basic and DevExpress WinForm and I made a simple example below to show my problem.
In the code is a Form with SimpleButton.
Clicking the button shows XtraDialog with User Control.
The User Control has a TextBox.

What I wish to do, is to get the input of this TextBox out of the User Control, into the Form, and not using a Module or SQL-Table, but like a DevExpress Input Box, through the Ok button.

Place use the example below, I'm very new to DevExpress and up to now still had any success implementing DevExpress into my code

```
Imports DevExpress.XtraEditors
Imports DevExpress.XtraLayout
Imports System
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class XtraDialog1
Inherits Form

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    AddHandler Me.SimpleButton1.Click, AddressOf simpleButton1_Click
End Sub

' Button Action
Private Sub simpleButton1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    ' Declare User Control
    Dim myControl As New ucExample()

  ' Show Popup
    If DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraDialog.Show(myControl, "Title", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) = DialogResult.OK Then
        ' do something
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

UserControl

```
Public Class ucExample

Dim result As String
Public Sub New()
    result = TextEdit1.Text
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit rusty on my DX stuff, but pretty sure all you need to do is change the access modifier and make *result* public.  Would recommend reading up on Access Modifiers because the idea is that you should keep it as restrictive as possible. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/declared-elements/access-levels.

I would use a readonly property for this, you might want to play around a little as to where it goes in the stack (ie In the user control, or the XtraDialog).  There is also a Modifier property for components in the Form and UserControl designers you may want to familiarise yourself with.

Changing the UC to this:

```
Public Class ucExample
    Public ReadOnly Property result As String
        Get
            Return TextEdit1.Text
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Sub New()
        result = TextEdit1.Text
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then I also thing you want to change the usage of your Dialog a little to get the result.

```
Dim dlg As New DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraDialog()
If dlg.Show(myControl, "Title", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) = DialogResult.OK Then
    Dim result As String = dlg.result
End If
```

Unable to test this myself right now, as don't have access to DX right now but hope this should be enough to get you heading in the right direction

Comment: Thx for the response. I understand what you're trying to do, but declaring the dlg like that doesn't work. It shows an error which me and college don't know how to handle. 

Class DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraDialog
A message box that allows displaying any control (e.g., a UserControl) in its client area.
Overload resolution failed because no 'New' is accessible.

also, dlg.result is not a member of 'XtraDialog'. but that is probably linked to the first problem

Answer (score 0):

After some research and help from DevExpressUserSupport, here is a working version

Form

```
Public Class XtraDialog2

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim myControl As New ucExample()
    If DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraDialog.Show(myControl, "Title", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) = DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim result As String = myControl.result
        MsgBox(result)
    End If

End Sub

End Class
```

User Control

```
Public Class ucExample
Public ReadOnly Property result As String
    Get
        Return TextEdit1.Text
    End Get
End Property
```

End Class